# React .map() access multiple elements at a time or using something like for loop

Tags: reactjs

I have products array with product objects, I need to something like

here Product is a component

```js
products.map(product) => {
  return(
    <div>
    <Product prop=product[i] />
    <Product prop=product[i+1]/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Bascially, I need two product components to be displayed within a single div like
for( i = 0 ; i < length ; i=+2 )

```js
<div>
<Product prop=product[i]/>
<Product prop=product[i+1]/>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, please provide complete problem description. I personally did not understand what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the `index` argument present in the `map` function which provides you the index of the current element.

```
{
  products.map((product, index) => (
    <div>
      <Product prop={products[index]} />
      <Product prop={products[index + 1]} />
    </div>
  ));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use 2 `map` like this:

```
products.map(product => {
  return product.map(item => {
    return(
      <Product product={item} />
    )
  }
}
```